# Binary search works best with which data structure?

Tags: binary-search

Binary search works best with which data structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One that is sorted and allows random access.

Comment: BSTs also provide binary search, so random access is not a requirement; being able to halve the search space in O(1) time is.

Comment: @Ed Heal But For Binary search data must be in sorted form.

Comment: Sorted array or a complete binary tree?